# PEVerify Defect: It reports "Type load failed" on valid class compiled with csc.exe for compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, cil, csc, peverify

A trivial class:

```
public class TestClass : System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityCredentialsManager { }
```

When compiled using csc against the MS CompactFramework v3.5 will result in a dll that fails to pass peverify, resulting in a "Type load failure".

It appears to be an issue with inheriting from the SecurityCredentialsManager class which is part of the MS supplied framework but I can't seem to identify why this class is problematic.

Reflection shows the signature of this class to be:

```
public abstract class SecurityCredentialsManager
{
    // Methods
    protected SecurityCredentialsManager()    {    }

    internal static SecurityTokenManager CreateSecurityTokenManager(SecurityCredentialsManager credMgr)    {    }
}
```

or in IL:

```
.class public abstract auto ansi beforefieldinit SecurityCredentialsManager
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method family hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed    {    }

    .method assembly hidebysig static class System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenManager CreateSecurityTokenManager(class System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityCredentialsManager credMgr) cil managed   { }

}
```

Inheriting from other classes in this System.ServiceModel assembly does not result in the error so it's not an assembly resolution issue.

I've tried running this script below in a VS 2005 and VS 2017 command window but it doesn't seem to be VS version dependent.

Here's a transcript of the toolchain invocation demonstrating the error:

```
H:\git\Test>TYPE Test.cs 
namespace Test
{
    public class TestClass : System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityCredentialsManager { }
}
H:\git\Test>Csc.exe /noconfig /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCpu /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.ServiceModel.dll" /target:library Test.cs  
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.7.0.62715 (db02128e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


H:\git\Test>peverify.exe Test.dll 

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework PE Verifier.  Version  4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[token  0x02000002] Type load failed.
1 Error(s) Verifying Test.dll

H:\git\Test>ildasm.exe /TEXT /ALL /CAVERBAL Test.dll 

//  Microsoft (R) .NET Framework IL Disassembler.  Version 4.6.1055.0
//  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


// ----- DOS Header:
// Magic:                      0x5a4d
// Bytes on last page:         0x0090
// Pages in file:              0x0003
// Relocations:                0x0000
// Size of header (paragraphs):0x0004
// Min extra paragraphs:       0x0000
// Max extra paragraphs:       0xffff
// Initial (relative) SS:      0x0000
// Initial SP:                 0x00b8
// Checksum:                   0x0000
// Initial IP:                 0x0000
// Initial (relative) CS:      0x0000
// File addr. of reloc table:  0x0040
// Overlay number:             0x0000
// OEM identifier:             0x0000
// OEM info:                   0x0000
// File addr. of COFF header:  0x0080
// ----- COFF/PE Headers:
// Signature:                  0x00004550
// ----- COFF Header:
// Machine:                    0x014c
// Number of sections:         0x0003
// Time-date stamp:            0x5b182555
// Ptr to symbol table:        0x00000000
// Number of symbols:          0x00000000
// Size of optional header:    0x00e0
// Characteristics:            0x2022
// ----- PE Optional Header (32 bit):
// Magic:                          0x010b
// Major linker version:           0x30
// Minor linker version:           0x00
// Size of code:                   0x00000400
// Size of init.data:              0x00000600
// Size of uninit.data:            0x00000000
// Addr. of entry point:           0x000022d2
// Base of code:                   0x00002000
// Base of data:                   0x00004000
// Image base:                     0x10000000
// Section alignment:              0x00002000
// File alignment:                 0x00000200
// Major OS version:               0x0004
// Minor OS version:               0x0000
// Major image version:            0x0000
// Minor image version:            0x0000
// Major subsystem version:        0x0004
// Minor subsystem version:        0x0000
// Size of image:                  0x00008000
// Size of headers:                0x00000200
// Checksum:                       0x00000000
// Subsystem:                      0x0003
// DLL characteristics:            0x8540
// Size of stack reserve:          0x00100000
// Size of stack commit:           0x00001000
// Size of heap reserve:           0x00100000
// Size of heap commit:            0x00001000
// Loader flags:                   0x00000000
// Directories:                    0x00000010
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Export Directory:          
// 0x00002280 [0x0000004f] address [size] of Import Directory:          
// 0x00004000 [0x00000298] address [size] of Resource Directory:        
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Exception Directory:       
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Security Directory:        
// 0x00006000 [0x0000000c] address [size] of Base Relocation Table:     
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Debug Directory:           
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Architecture Specific:     
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Global Pointer:            
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of TLS Directory:             
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Load Config Directory:     
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Bound Import Directory:    
// 0x00002000 [0x00000008] address [size] of Import Address Table:      
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Delay Load IAT:            
// 0x00002008 [0x00000048] address [size] of CLR Header:                


// Image sections:
//              .text
//              0x000002d8 Virtual Size
//              0x00002000 Virtual Address
//              0x00000400 Size of Raw Data
//              0x00000200 Pointer to Raw Data
//              0x00000000 Pointer to Relocations
//              0x00000000 Pointer to Linenumbers
//                  0x0000 Number of Relocations
//                  0x0000 Number of Linenumbers
//              0x60000020 Characteristics
//                         CNT_CODE
//                         MEM_EXECUTE
//                         MEM_READ

//              .rsrc
//              0x00000298 Virtual Size
//              0x00004000 Virtual Address
//              0x00000400 Size of Raw Data
//              0x00000600 Pointer to Raw Data
//              0x00000000 Pointer to Relocations
//              0x00000000 Pointer to Linenumbers
//                  0x0000 Number of Relocations
//                  0x0000 Number of Linenumbers
//              0x40000040 Characteristics
//                         CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
//                         MEM_READ

//              .reloc
//              0x0000000c Virtual Size
//              0x00006000 Virtual Address
//              0x00000200 Size of Raw Data
//              0x00000a00 Pointer to Raw Data
//              0x00000000 Pointer to Relocations
//              0x00000000 Pointer to Linenumbers
//                  0x0000 Number of Relocations
//                  0x0000 Number of Linenumbers
//              0x42000040 Characteristics
//                         CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
//                         MEM_DISCARDABLE
//                         MEM_READ

// Base Relocation Table
//              0x00002000 Page RVA
//              0x0000000c Block Size
//              0x00000002 Number of Entries
//              Entry 1: Type 0x3 Offset 0x000002d4
//              Entry 2: Type 0x0 Offset 0x00000000

// Import Address Table
//     DLL : mscoree.dll
//              0x00002000 Import Address Table
//              0x000022c2 Import Name Table
//              0          Time Date Stamp
//              0          Index of First Forwarder Reference
//
//              0x0000  _CorDllMain

// Delay Load Import Address Table
// No data.

// Entry point code:
//FF 25 00 20 00 10 


// ----- CLR Header:
// Header size:                        0x00000048
// Major runtime version:              0x0002
// Minor runtime version:              0x0005
// 0x0000205c [0x00000224] address [size] of Metadata Directory:        
// Flags:                              0x00000001
// Entry point token:                  0x00000000
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Resources Directory:       
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Strong Name Signature:     
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of CodeManager Table:         
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of VTableFixups Directory:    
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Export Address Table:      
// 0x00000000 [0x00000000] address [size] of Precompile Header:         

// Metadata Header
//    Storage Signature:
//              0x424a5342 Signature
//                  0x0001 Major Version
//                  0x0001 Minor Version
//              0x00000000 Extra Data Offset
//              0x0000000c Version String Length
//              'v2.0.50727' Version String
//    Storage Header:
//                    0x00 Flags
//                  0x0005 Number of Streams
//    Stream 1:
//              0x0000006c Offset
//              0x000000d0 Size
//              '#~' Name
//    Stream 2:
//              0x0000013c Offset
//              0x000000b4 Size
//              '#Strings' Name
//    Stream 3:
//              0x000001f0 Offset
//              0x00000004 Size
//              '#US' Name
//    Stream 4:
//              0x000001f4 Offset
//              0x00000010 Size
//              '#GUID' Name
//    Stream 5:
//              0x00000204 Offset
//              0x00000020 Size
//              '#Blob' Name

//    Metadata Stream Header:
//              0x00000000 Reserved
//                    0x02 Major
//                    0x00 Minor
//                    0x00 Heaps
//                    0x01 Rid
//      0x0000000900001447 MaskValid
//      0x000016003301fa00 Sorted

// Code Manager Table:
//  default


// Export Address Table Jumps:
// No data.

// File size            : 3072
// PE header size       : 512 (496 used)    (16.67%)
// PE additional info   : 835               (27.18%)
// Num.of PE sections   : 3
// CLR header size     : 72                 ( 2.34%)
// CLR meta-data size  : 548                (17.84%)
// CLR additional info : 0                  ( 0.00%)
// CLR method headers  : 1                  ( 0.03%)
// Managed code         : 8                 ( 0.26%)
// Data                 : 1536              (50.00%)
// Unaccounted          : -440              (-14.32%)

// Num.of PE sections   : 3
//   .text    - 1024
//   .rsrc    - 1024
//   .reloc   - 512

// CLR meta-data size  : 548
//   Module        -    1 (10 bytes)
//   TypeDef       -    2 (28 bytes)      0 interfaces, 0 explicit layout
//   TypeRef       -    3 (18 bytes)
//   MethodDef     -    1 (14 bytes)      0 abstract, 0 native, 1 bodies
//   MemberRef     -    2 (12 bytes)
//   CustomAttribute-    1 (6 bytes)
//   Assembly      -    1 (22 bytes)
//   AssemblyRef   -    2 (40 bytes)
//   Strings       -   179 bytes
//   Blobs         -    32 bytes
//   UserStrings   -     4 bytes
//   Guids         -    16 bytes
//   Uncategorized -   167 bytes

// CLR method headers : 1
//   Num.of method bodies  - 1
//   Num.of fat headers    - 0
//   Num.of tiny headers   - 1

// Managed code : 8
//   Ave method size - 8
// Classes defined in this module:
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Class TestClass                      (public) (auto) (ansi) 
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


// Metadata version: v2.0.50727
.assembly extern /*23000001*/ mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (96 9D B8 05 3D 33 22 AC )                         // ....=3".
  .ver 3:5:0:0
}
.assembly extern /*23000002*/ retargetable System.ServiceModel
{
  .publickeytoken = (96 9D B8 05 3D 33 22 AC )                         // ....=3".
  .ver 3:5:0:0
}
.assembly /*20000001*/ Test
{

  // --- The following custom attribute is added automatically, do not uncomment -------
  //  .custom /*0C000001:0A000001*/ instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/*01000001*/::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/*01000001*//DebuggingModes/*01000002*/) /* 0A000001 */
  //           = {int32(263)}
  //    //     = ( 01 00 07 01 00 00 00 00 ) 

  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 0:0:0:0
}
.module Test.dll
// MVID: {4D00E592-C83B-48AC-9DD0-AEF1C5C0B337}
.imagebase 0x10000000
.file alignment 0x00000200
.stackreserve 0x00100000
.subsystem 0x0003       // WINDOWS_CUI
.corflags 0x00000001    //  ILONLY
// Image base: 0x00460000


// =============== CLASS MEMBERS DECLARATION ===================

.class /*02000002*/ public auto ansi beforefieldinit Test.TestClass
       extends [System.ServiceModel/*23000002*/]System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityCredentialsManager/*01000003*/
{
  .method /*06000001*/ public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  // SIG: 20 00 01
  {
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size       8 (0x8)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  /* 02   |                  */ ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  /* 28   | (0A)000002       */ call       instance void [System.ServiceModel/*23000002*/]System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityCredentialsManager/*01000003*/::.ctor() /* 0A000002 */
    IL_0006:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
    IL_0007:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
  } // end of method TestClass::.ctor

} // end of class Test.TestClass


// =============================================================

// *********** DISASSEMBLY COMPLETE ***********************
```

Comment: Apparently if I declare the TestClass as abstract then the peverify reports no errors.  But leaving the class as non-abstract causes the type load error to be reported.  This seems to be a defect in peverify since the compiler generates this valid code and the CLR can execute without a problem, but peverify still chokes on it.

Comment: I do not have the compact framework assemblies at hand, but the references source shows `CreateSecurityTokenManager` as abstract, meaning you have to implement it to get a valid type. Maybe there is some kind of inconsistency in different framework versions and/or some magic at assembly resolution. Also your IL-dump says `retargetable` for the assembly in question, that could be a hint. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Security/SecurityCredentialsManager.cs